# toLocaleString is not working in react Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, mern

to convert given  date and time 
as par "new york" timezone, tried following, 
it works perfect but only on android emulator,
But when tested on an actual device gives an invalid date

```js
const date = new Date("2019-08-12T09:58:00.000Z")
  .toLocaleString("en-US", {
    timeZone: "America/New_York"
  });

console.log(date);
```

Comment: hello, quick question. are you sure the problem is with `toLocaleString` ? the Date format `2019-08-12T09:58:00.000Z` is working properly ?

Comment: yup I tried different date formats, it works, no issue about date format

Comment: There are date mismatches depending on Android API. Read this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16867

Comment: 8/12/2019, 5:58:00 AM is this invalid data ?

Comment: @jsduniya, absolutely not, but when tried on actual device it shows as invalid date

Comment: usually `invalid date` appears when `new Date(...)` returns an invalid date...obviously :) did you try to use only the new Date on device, without `toLocaleString` ? just to confirm that `new Date(..)` is working properly ?

Comment: I bypassed the problem using the "moment" library

Answer (score 2):

You'll see this problem if you're using Hermes or some Android JS engines, but it's easy enough to polyfill.

```
yarn add intl
```

In your index.js or other base file:

```
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

And now it works properly throughout your app.